# Flutter form in Container, when validator works Container comes too small for Form

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-container, flutter-form-builder, flutter-column

Im a new flutter developer, so please can u help me with this problem.
The problem is when validator in TextFieldForm "works" it adds text that user did something wrong.
And my Container is become to small for Form. I need to stretch the container or do something else to get better result. I dont know what should i do, please can u help me, for this.

here is my code:

```
body:Center(
      child:SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Column(
          children[ 
            Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                  ),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9,
                  // width: 350,
                  // height: 600,
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: ListView(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                      // itemExtent: 60,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: _validateName,
                          controller: _nameController,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.person,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: 'Adyňyz',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(10),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: _validatePassword,
                          controller: _passController,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          obscureText: _hidePass,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.shield,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _hidePass = !_hidePass;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(
                                  _hidePass
                                      ? Icons.visibility
                                      : Icons.visibility_off,
                                )),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: 'Parol',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(10),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _teamNameController,
                          validator: _validateTeam,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.people),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: 'Toparyň ady',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(10),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _phoneNumberController,
                          validator: _validatePhoneNumber,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            helperText: "+993-6#-######",
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.grey),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: "Telefon nomeriňiz",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(10),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 60,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _submitButton();
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Register",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                              ),
                            ),
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              backgroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),],
),
),
),
```

Here is a first look :
[image],

and here is the problem:

[image],

[image]

This what am i talking about.

I dont have any idea about this. please guys, i need ur help.
and thank u a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove fixed height from container `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9,`. Just use `SingleChildScrollView` on Column and remove ListView widget.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20), //config
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Form(
          // key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                // validator: _validateName,
                // controller: _nameController,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintText: 'Adyňyz',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                // validator: _validatePassword,
                // controller: _passController,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                // obscureText: _hidePass,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.shield,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  // suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  //     color: Colors.black,
                  //     onPressed: () {
                  // setState(() {
                  //   _hidePass = !_hidePass;
                  // });
                  // },
                  // icon: Icon(
                  //   _hidePass
                  //       ? Icons.visibility
                  //       : Icons.visibility_off,
                  // )
                  // ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintText: 'Parol',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                // controller: _teamNameController,
                // validator: _validateTeam,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.people),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintText: 'Toparyň ady',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                // controller: _phoneNumberController,
                // validator: _validatePhoneNumber,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  helperText: "+993-6#-######",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.grey),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintText: "Telefon nomeriňiz",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // _submitButton();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Register",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `ListView`, because you have already wrapped with `SingleChildScrollView`.

You have to either use `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView` to achieve scroll effect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you already gave height to the container i.e

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9
```

at above code your container height is independent of the form validation and without showing any validation all the fields will show But when validation error occurs then error text will be shown which will takes additional height and here you are using Single child child scroll view but the container height is same as before without error text

So now the easiest way to solve this issue is

Remove container height parameter means don't set its height because container will automatically takes the size as much as its child. Now by doing this the container will automatically shrink when there is no error text and will automatically expand when there is error texts